# Create mixed orientation PDF in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am merging PDF buffers using this code at http://web.archive.org/web/20111012184438/http://alex.buayacorp.com/merge-pdf-files-with-itext-and-net.html [[Mirror]](http://pastebin.com/L1xbd1SZ)

My PDFs have mixed page orientation, some are portrait and some are landscape (but all are A4)

The code does not maintain the orientation of each page and uses the orientation of the first page throughout the document. How do I go about creating a mixed orientation PDF using this code.

Comment: The link is invalid. Without it the question is almost useless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trick to using multiple page sizes is to call `SetPageSize()` just before calling `NewPage()`. Something like this should work (I didn't compile this but it should be pretty close):

```
PdfImportedPage importedPage = pdfWriter.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, page);
newDocument.SetPageSize(new iTextSharp.Text.Rectangle(0.0F, 0.0F, importedPage.Width, importedPage.Height));
newDocument.NewPage();
pdfContentByte.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Chris Haas.  I needed page 3 to be landscape

```
        if (PageNumber == 3)
        {
           pDoc.SetPageSize(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(0,0,PageSize.LETTER.Height,PageSize.LETTER.Width));
        }
        pDoc.NewPage();
```

Comment: This code assumes that all pages are the LETTER size, versus having mixed page sizes in a document.